# How to make multiple breaks using CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have so bad habit in Web Design, and im trying to fix that (I dont use table layouts ;-)).

I just want to know good way to bring a div down.

for example:

```
<div class="container">
    <p>
        something like this
    </p>
</div>
```

I just want to bring the div down.

I like to do things the right way but Its much faster to do

```
<br /><br /><br /><br />
```

This is very ugly I need your help to avoid this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give a Margin top style to bring the div down

```
<div class="container" style="Margin-Top:25px;">
    <p>
        something like this
    </p>
</div>
```

[**Demo Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/s2j43/)

More the margin you provide more it will shift down use accordingly :)

Comment: This is what I was looking For thanks man. When I get some more rep I will up vote it.

Answer (score 0):

in your css add

```
.container { margin-top: 30px; }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS file add the following:

```
.container {
    margin-top: 20px;
}
```

Or if you want to move the p tag down inside the container do one of the following:

```
.container p {
    margin-top: 20px;
}
```

or

```
.container {
   padding-top: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use either `margin-top` or `position:absolute and then top:some value` or `padding-top`

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bEdrs/)

Use any one of these CSS

**1.**

```
.container{
    margin-top:50px;
}
```

**2.**

```
.container{
    position:absolute;
    top:50px;
}
```

**3.**

```
.container{
    padding-top:50px;
}
```